# Error: Incorrect number of dimension

Tags: r

I am trying to perform an analysis on stock portfolio utilising short weights.

To be able to do so, I had to create a loop that would tranform my "normal" returns to the opposite sign (+/-), whenever the corresponding weight is "short" (negative sign).

The matrix **mat_weights** contains the optimazed weigths of 34 different portfolios, each one containing an increasing number of stocks that vary depending on an optimization process ("Markovitz"):

- 1st portfolio : 4 stocks
- 2nd portfolio: 5 stocks
- 3rd portfolio : 6 stocks
- ........
- 34th portfolio: 34 stocks

The matrix **mat_returns_adjusted** is a matrix that should contain the result of the loop, which should be the returns corrisponding to each stock changed of sign if the corrisponding porfolio weight is negative. 
So in the end I should be able to obtain a 1040(rows)x 34(columns) matrix filled with the "adjusted" returns.

The matrix **mat_returns_raw** contains the returns of each stock linked to another matrix called **nomi** that connects the right stock return with the name of the corresponding stock

This is the for loop discussed above:

```
for(i in 1:34) {
mat_weights_short <- (mat_weights[i,1:i+3])
mat_returns_adjusted <- matrix (NA,1040,i+3)
mat_returns_raw <- returns[,nomi[i,1:i+3]]
if(mat_weights_short[i]<0) {
mat_returns_adjusted[,i]<- -(mat_returns_raw[,i])
} else {
mat_returns_adjusted[,i]<- mat_returns_raw[,i]
}}
```

When I enter this into R console i receive an error message:

```
Error in mat_returns_raw[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I tried to solve the problem but I haven't been able to resolve it so far.
I apologise in advance if the question isn't that clear but it's the first time I had to use R.
Any help would be immensely apreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue most likely is mat_returns_raw isnt the correct object/size.  Try this to make the issue more obvious.

```
for(i in 1:34) {
    mat_weights_short <- (mat_weights[i,1:i+3])
    mat_returns_adjusted <- matrix (NA,1040,i+3)
    mat_returns_raw <- returns[,nomi[i,1:i+3]]

    ## print updates
    print(paste0("You're trying to pull column ", i " out of a ", class(mat_returns_raw), " which has ", ncol(mat_returns_raw), " columns"))
    flush.console()

    if(mat_weights_short[i]<0) {
        mat_returns_adjusted[,i]<- -(mat_returns_raw[,i])
    } else {
        mat_returns_adjusted[,i]<- mat_returns_raw[,i]
    }
}
```

Also, I suggest running the `for` loop, typing `i` into your console to find which iteration the error is occuring in, then running code line-by-line in your `for` loop to manually figure out where the problem is, using things like `dim()` and `class()` often to look for anything you don't expect.  Good luck

Comment: I tried to run the loop for each code line and apparently the problem is with **mat_weights-short**, which as i run dim() gives me a **NULL** result and it gives me the **error("out of bounds")**. Any suggestions on how to address the problem?

Comment: I would make sure that `length(mat_weights_short) >= 34`, it is a vector, so you would want to check it with `length` instead of `dim`.  I'm guessing that your `if` statement is bugging because its looking for an iteration of `i` past its actual length (example `i = 21` but the `length(mat_weights_short) = 20`, so its looking at the 21'st element and the 21st element doesnt exist since its length is only 20).  sounds like "out of bounds" to me.

Comment: I just run `length(mat_weights_short)` and it's equal to 34. It's actual length it's 31, that's why i added **+3**

Comment: can you please take a look at my answer if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65781259/plot-causes-error-incorrect-number-of-dimensions-r-language thanks!